# Hot to get count of connection in SignalR Core Group

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

How can I get count of connections in specific SignalR Core group?

Something like that:

```
this.Clients.Group("Something").Count();
```

It would be also good if `SendAsync` would return how many clients send message:

```
var count = await this.Clients.Client(this.Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("msg", msg);
```

I need this to determine if group is empty. Data should be correct if user disconnects from SignalR Core with force (unplug net cable)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OnConnected and OnDisconnected Events and save the connection / connectionIds.

I use something like this with additional informations:

```cs
internal static ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConnectionInfos> Users = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConnectionInfos>();

public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    var connId = Context.ConnectionId;
    if (!Users.Keys.Any(x => x == connId))
    {
        Users.TryAdd(connId, new ConnectionInfos { /*...*/});
    }
    await base.OnConnectedAsync();
}

public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
{
    var id = Context.ConnectionId;
    if (Users.TryRemove(id, out ConnectionInfos ci))
    {
        //Connection removed
    }
    await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
}
```

Comment: Note: This won't give you a reliable count if you have multiple servers. This is why we don't provide a built-in way to do this. When you have multiple servers, each server only knows about connections on that server.

Comment: That's correct, but actually I have not seen any simple way to know all connections. Actually there is no build-in solution and no simple solution for multi-server configurations.

Comment: @AndrewStanton-Nurse I have the exact situation that you mentioned, I have a load balancer, SignalR uses Redis for persisting connections, but I still have to map the connections to users, something similar to:

`private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConnectionInfos> `

How can I do this? Do I have to use Redis manually to persist this dictionary? Can I utilize the built-in SignalR mechanism that connects to Redis, and inject that dictionary in the data sent to Redis?

Comment: @AndrewStanton-Nurse if this doesn't work for multi-server env, how is Clients.All handled then?

Comment: OP was specifically asking about group count - this solution does nothing for group count.

Comment: The question was changed as you can see in the comments. But for Groups you can use the same mechanism with Group Join and Leave. And also this is only for single server. For multiple servers you need to save the connection infos in another way like Redis.